# Python Concatenation without using Join

Tags: python

I'm trying to make something that takes as input a list of strings, and returns a string that is the concatenation all those strings together. However, I'm trying to learn how to do it without the join method.

Here is the main bulk of my code:

```
def concat_list(p):

def main():
    list = []
    i = 1
    print('Entering the empty string stops the input process.')
    while True:
        str_input = str(input('Enter string #' + str(i) + ': '))
        if str_input == '':    # empty string -> stop input process
            if i > 1:
                list.pop()     # remove the last element ' ' from list
            break
        i = i + 1
        list.append(str_input)
        list.append(' ')       # we want the user's input strings to be interspersed with ' '
                               # for instance: ['Python', ' ', 'is', 'so', ' ', 'cool']
    print(list)

main()
```

The def concat_list is what someone recommended using in order to store/call the new concatenated text. Does anyone have any suggestions? I've hit a block. Using the join method would simplify things I know but I want to try to do it without.

Comment: At the end if you wanna convert that list into a string you have to use join, or use an inefficient and expensive string concatenation like `string += substring`

Answer (score 0):

join() is usually a better/more idiomatic approach, but you can also concatenate strings with `+` or `+=`:

```
>>> l = ['this', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'test']
>>> l
['this', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'test']

>>> def concat_list(l):
...    s = ''
...    for word in l:
...       s += word
...    return s
...
>>> concat_list(l)
'this is a test'
```

Comment: okay, so that's what the concat_list was for, basically acting as a place to store the strings that are going to be concatenated. This makes a little more sense thank you!

Comment: Better to think of it that `concat_list` is a function that accepts a single parameter (a list containing strings) and combines them together into a single string `s` that's returned to the code that calls the function.

Comment: what is the s in that block of code? Or how would it relate to the p that's in mine?

Comment: Or more appropriately, how would I store the list that is being made in the Main() function so that it can be called using the Concat_list function. That's what's been hanging me up.

Comment: Pretty sure @bgporter answered that already with his example.  Create a function called `concat_list` and right after your `input` pass the input string to `concat_list`.  Then you'll have your formatted string.  Only catch is that if you're using less than Python 3, I think you'll need to use `raw_input` rather than `input` to get the desired outcome.

Comment: No I'm using Python 3, so this should apply. But should I place my Concat_list before or after my Main() function? Because he used concat_list(1) but my variable is (p). Again this is what threw me.

Comment: You should go through the Python tutorial to understand more about creating and using functions -- look starting here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions